# Transparent Single Sign On within Identity Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, openid, owin, identityserver3

Following scenario: I'm successfully authenticated in application A, token and cookie is issued. Later I go to the application B. Application B is ASP.NET MVC application. Now when I click the Login button I'm, as expected, successfully logged-in without redirection to the Login page. But I would like to be logged-in without to click on Login button. So when I come to the home page the button shows "Logout", but do not redirect anywhere when I'm not authenticated, until I click on the "Login" button. Now I'm using standard OWIN Middleware and Authorize Attribute. What is the proper way and alternatives to achieve this? Need I write own Authorize Attribut filter?

Answer (score 0):

From the 2nd app you can trigger a "silent" login attempt via an iframe passing prompt=none in the authorization request. If the user is already logged in, then they will get a response immediately (success of failure). Check the docs for the params: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

Comment: Hi Brock, thank you for your fast answer. Can you give me pls. a hint to example? Is there any sample in your http://https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples)IdentityServer3.Samples?

Comment: I don't think we have any samples that show this. Sorry.